# Files changes are not showing in vscode source control

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I make a change to a file in the project folder, the 'SOURCE CONTROL: GIT' panel is missing **changes** section.Because of that I am not able to see modified file .
Please check below image of how my vscode is looking(changes section is mising here)

[image: Below is the image of my vscode]

Comment: What kind of file is it? Is it possible that its being ignored by your .gitignore?

Comment: Its a project and inside of that there are many js file .Previously when I was doing changes and any file ,I see those modified file in changes section.Now changes section is missing so I am not abe to see those files.